# Finding a minimal polynomial of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear operator, is there a straightforward way to find a minimal polynomial? I just learned that minimal polynomial can give information about the diagonalizability of the matrix, but I wonder how practical this technique is.

I understand that minimal polynomial divides characteristic polynomial, but that is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe not.  If there were, then diagonalizing matrices would be known to be pretty easy, and it's not.

For small matrices, you can compute the characteristic polynomial using determinants; the minimal polynomial is then one of its divisors, of which there are only a few possibilities. And certainly every distinct linear factor (over the complexes) should appear in the minimal polynomial to degree at least one, so the number of things to try is small.

Once you know the Jordan normal form of the matrix, you can find the minimal polynomial easily, but that's going the other direction from what you want, I believe.